Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). I am working on creating a weather app however, it is showing me error
I am working on creating a weather app however, it is showing me this error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')".Below is the javascript code.
let apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=";
let searchBox = document.querySelector(".search input");
let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search button");

async function FetchWeatherDataByCityName(city) {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl + city + `&appid=${apiKey}`);
  var data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  //   handleTemp.innerHTML =
  //   handleWeatherIcon.innerHTML = data.weather[0].main;

  document.querySelector(".city-heading").innerHTML = data.name;
  document.querySelector(".temp-heading").innerHTML =
    Math.round(data.main.temp) + "°C";
  document.querySelector(".weather-icon").innerHTML = data.weather[0].main;
  document.querySelector(".h3-humidity-heading").innerHTML =
    data.main.humidity + "%";
  document.querySelector(".h3-wind-speed").innerHTML =
    data.wind.speed + " Km/h";

  // Choosing the weather icon
  if (data.weather[0].main == "Clouds") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/clouds.png";
  } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Clear") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/clear.png";
  } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Drizzle") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/drizzle.png";
  } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Mist") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/mist.png";
  } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Rain") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/rain.png";
  } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Snow") {
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/snow.png";
  }
}

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  FetchWeatherDataByCityName(searchBox.value);
});

// Here is the html code. Adding some text to balance the code to text ratio for submitting the question. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.:
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="body-styles">
    <div class="weather-app-card">
      <div class="input-and-search-icon-styling">
        <div class="search">
          <input
            class="search-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter City Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="search">
          <button class="search-icon-btn">
            <img class="search-icon" src="./images/search.png" alt="" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <img class="weather-icon" src="./images/clear.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="temp-heading">7°C</h1>
        <h2 class="city-heading">New York</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="humidity-and-wind-speed">
        <div class="humidity-icon-and-text">
          <div>
            <img class="humidity-image" src="./images/humidity.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="humidity-percentage">
            <h3 class="h3-humidity-heading">48%</h3>
            <h4 class="h4-humidity">Humidity</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wind-speed-icon-and-text">
          <div>
            <img class="wind-image" src="./images/wind.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3 class="h3-wind-speed">10.29Km/h</h3>
            <h4 class="h4-wind-speed">wind speed</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



You likely need to wrap it in a load event handler or move the script to the bottom of the page, but your post does not show where you run the script. Please show the relevant HTML so we can help you better

It would be useful to have more context on the html file, "Cannot read properties of null" means there's nothing on searchBtn, therefore, the querySelector couldn't find the button you were looking for.

I have attached the html file

There were more issues with your code apart from this. See my answer for improvements

Most likely cause
Your JS is trying to access an element in your page at a point in time, when the browser hasn't parsed the page yet. This commonly happens if you put your external <script src="/path/to/your.js"></script> in the <head> of the page.
When doing so, the browser stops parsing at that point to load the JavaScript referenced in the src-attribute of the <script>-tag, and executes it immediately. At this point no element below that <script>-tag in the HTML document is accessible to JS.
3 way to fix

The easiest fix in this scenario is to put a defer attribute on the <script>-tag:
<script src="/path/to/your.js" defer></script>




This will allow the browser to load the referenced JS file, but wait until the whole page is parsed before it runs the code.


Wrap your code in a DOMContentLoaded listener:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // move your code here
});




This will run the code once the browser issues the event that notifies code listening for it that the parsing of the page is completed.


Move the <script>-tag to the end of the document, right before the closing </body>-tag. This way the browser only encounters your script when everything else in the body has already been parsed, since browsers parse documents top-down.

Other possible causes
If you're already making sure your JS isn't executed too early, another possible cause for your error could be that your querySelector are trying to select an element in the page based on a selector that doesn't match anything inside your HTML structure.

Do we not have a ton of dupes for this? There were more issues in the code

@mplungjan Ofc we have, this is probably among the top 3 of errors that beginners in JS run into. When I decided to answer, the source of the problem wasn't completely clear yet (no HTML was provided), so I decided to answer instead of closing as duplicate. Once the effort was spent, I didn't want to delete it either.

You need to wrap it in a load event handler
Here is a simpler working version using your HTML where I fixed some icon issues too


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const apiKey = "bd5e378503939ddaee76f12ad7a97608"; // found on the internet, please change for your own
  const apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=";
  const form = document.querySelector(".search");
  const searchBox = form.querySelector("input");

  async function FetchWeatherDataByCityName(city) {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${city}&appid=${apiKey}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const { name, main, weather, wind } = data;
    const { temp, humidity } = main; // spread
    document.querySelector(".city-heading").innerHTML = name;
    document.querySelector(".temp-heading").innerHTML = `${Math.round(temp)}°C`;
    document.querySelector(".h4-humidity").innerHTML = `${humidity}%`;
    //console.log({wind})
    document.querySelector(".h4-wind-speed").innerHTML = `${wind.speed}Km/h`;

    // Choosing the weather icon
    const iconSrc = weather[0].main; 
    const icon = document.querySelector(".weather-icon");
    icon.src = ["Clouds", "Clear", "Drizzle", "Mist", "Rain", "Snow"]
      .includes(iconSrc) ? `images/${iconSrc.toLowerCase()}.png` : `images/unknown.png`;
    icon.alt = iconSrc;
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = searchBox.value;
    FetchWeatherDataByCityName(city); // run on load  - remove if you do not want to do that
  });
  FetchWeatherDataByCityName("New York"); // initial
});
<div class="weather-app-card">
  <div class="input-and-search-icon-styling">
    <form class="search">
      <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" value="New York"/>
      <button type="submit" class="search-icon-btn">
            <img class="search-icon" src="./images/search.png" alt="" />
          </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img class="weather-icon" src="./images/clear.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="temp-heading"></h1>
    <h2 class="city-heading"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="humidity-and-wind-speed">
    <div class="humidity-icon-and-text">
      <div>
        <img class="humidity-image" src="./images/humidity.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="humidity-percentage">
        <h3 class="h3-humidity-heading">Humidity</h3>
        <h4 class="h4-humidity"></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wind-speed-icon-and-text">
      <div>
        <img class="wind-image" src="" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="h3-wind-speed-heading">Wind speed</h3>
        <h4 class="h4-wind-speed"></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Try with this javascript code


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=";
  let searchBox = document.querySelector(".search input");
  let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search button");

  async function FetchWeatherDataByCityName(city) {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl + city + `&appid=${apiKey}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    document.querySelector(".city-heading").innerHTML = data.name;
    document.querySelector(".temp-heading").innerHTML =
      Math.round(data.main.temp) + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".weather-icon").innerHTML = data.weather[0].main;
    document.querySelector(".h3-humidity-heading").innerHTML =
      data.main.humidity + "%";
    document.querySelector(".h3-wind-speed").innerHTML =
      data.wind.speed + " Km/h";

    // Choosing the weather icon
    if (data.weather[0].main == "Clouds") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/clouds.png";
    } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Clear") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/clear.png";
    } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Drizzle") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/drizzle.png";
    } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Mist") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/mist.png";
    } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Rain") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/rain.png";
    } else if (data.weather[0].main == "Snow") {
      document.querySelector(".weather-icon").src = "images/snow.png";
    }
  }

  // Check if searchBtn and searchBox are not null before adding event listener
  if (searchBtn && searchBox) {
    searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      FetchWeatherDataByCityName(searchBox.value);
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Search button or search input not found.");
  }
});



